# Column x contains an analytic function, which is not allowed in GROUP BY

Tags: group-by, google-bigquery

In BigQuery why am I getting an error saying: `Column x contains an analytic function, which is not allowed in GROUP BY`?

In this case UserId is a STRING type and date is a DATE type. The example code below finds aims to find how many users are seen for a given number of days. For example, we saw 10 users 11 days out of the 14 day time period.

Reproducible Code:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(UserId) AS Users,
  Days
FROM (
  SELECT
    DISTINCT gmt_via_cust_var_8 AS UserId,
    COUNT(date) OVER (PARTITION BY gmt_via_cust_var_8) AS Days
  FROM
    `pchmediadev.Joey.mini_impressions`
  GROUP BY
    Days
)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The issue is that the `GROUP BY` is being applied to the variable whose value will be determined by a window function. This is similar to the issue with grouping by an aggregate function.

The solution to this issue is to move the `GROUP BY` to the outer query. The outer query can do the grouping required.

See example below:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(UserId) AS Users,
  Days
FROM (
  SELECT
    DISTINCT gmt_via_cust_var_8 AS UserId,
    COUNT(date) OVER (PARTITION BY gmt_via_cust_var_8) AS Days
  FROM
    `pchmediadev.Joey.mini_impressions`
)
GROUP BY
  Days
```